# DrRacket: lambda anonymous function

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

What is the difference between `test1`:

```
(define test1
  (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

and `test2`

```
(define (test2 x)
  (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

Aren't both suppose to be the same. When I test `test1` I get an correct answer but `test2` returns `#<function>` or `(lambda (a1) ...)`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Test1 is equivalent to

```
(define (test3 x)
    (* x x))
```

In test2 you have a lambda too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (func-name argument)
  body))
```

This defines the **variable** `func-name` to be a function that takes one argument with `body` as the content of the function. It is an abbreviation for:

```
(define func-name (lambda (argument)
  body)
```

Your second example can thus be written like this:

```
(define test2 
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (x) (* x x))))
```

`test2` is a function **that returns a function**. Also since `x` is used in both the inner function will never have access to the argument. Imagine this instead:

```
(define (make-less-than value)
  (lambda (arg)
    (< arg value))

(filter (make-less-than 10) '(9 10 1 11 4 19))
; ==> (9 1 4)
```

So what happens is that `make-less-than` returns a function that checks if the passed argument is less than `value`, in this case `10`. It can be reused for other values. For just one time you could just as well have written:

```
(filter (lambda (v) (< v 10)) '(9 10 1 11 4 19))
```